Sample uniformly from the surface of a d-spherical cap
I would like to uniformly sample points from the d-spherical cap. The problem is as follow:
Given a point X generated on S^D and the maximum angular seperation theta, generate a point Y such as angle(X,Y) <= theta. The point Y should be generate uniformly from the d-spherical cap.
To generate a random point on S^D we can use the following code:
def get_point(N, D):
    X = np.random.randn(N, D + 1)
    X /= np.linalg.norm(X, axis=1)[:, np.newaxis]
    return X

I tried to apply the rotation matrix to a given input point X
def get_sample_around_point(point, theta_max):
    D = point.shape[0] - 1
    theta = np.random.uniform(0, theta_max)
 
    rotation_axis = np.random.normal(size=(D + 1,))
    rotation_axis /= np.linalg.norm(rotation_axis)
    cos_theta = np.cos(theta)
    sin_theta = np.sin(theta)
    rotation_matrix = (
        cos_theta * np.eye(D + 1)
        + sin_theta * np.outer(rotation_axis, rotation_axis)
        + (1 - cos_theta) * np.eye(D + 1)
    )
    
    new_point = np.dot(rotation_matrix, point.T).reshape(1, -1)
    new_point /= np.linalg.norm(new_point, axis=1)[:, np.newaxis]
    return new_point.flatten()

Example:
N = 1
D = 2
theta = np.pi/4
x = get_point(N, D)[0]
get_sample_around_point(x, theta)

However, the points are not sampled uniformly.
N = 1
D = 2
x = get_point(N, D)[0]
theta = np.pi/3
Y = np.array([get_sample_around_point(x, theta) for _ in range(500)])

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.scatter(x[0], x[1], x[2], label='X', s=500, color='black')
ax.scatter(Y[:, 0], Y[:, 1], Y[:, 2], color='red', label='')
ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_zlabel('Z')
plt.show()


To confirm it we can plot the histogram of angular distances from the sampled point x. The distribution is not uniform.


A uniform distribution of points would not have a uniform distribution of angles.  Higher angles (closer to the equator) should be more popular.

"To generate a random point on S^D we can use the following code:" <<< The code you show gives a random point, but not a uniformly-random point, of the sphere. You're mapping a cube onto a sphere by normalising the vector. Think about it: the cube has much more volume in directions corresponding to its vertices than in directions corresponding to the centre of its faces.

@MattTimmermans Let us take the S^1 (a circle) as the simplest case. If you sample uniformly around a given point X, then the distribution of the angular distance would be uniform. I want to achieve the same for higher dimensions.

@Stef, I am using the approach from Marsaglia (1972) (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere, section Uniformly at random on the (n − 1)-sphere).

Oops, you're right

@RobJan, consider the Earth.  There's a lot more surface around the equator than there is around the 80th parallel, so a uniform distribution of points will favor lower lattitudes.  The effect gets more pronounced in higher dimensions

Once you've selected an angle, the rest is easy, via an extension of Marsaglia's method.
Given a unit vector v pointing to the center of the cap you want, and an angle θ:

Choose a Gaussian-distributed point p in D+1 dimensions
Remove any projection on v: p -= v(p.v)
Set its distance from the origin to sin θ: p *= (sin θ)/|v|
Set is projection along v to cos θ: p += (cos θ)v

Unfortunately, choosing the angle seems difficult.  The density of points at angle θ is proportional to (sin θ)D-1.  To choose an angle, you need to integrate that.  It's not too difficult for any particular D, but for arbitrary D it's beyond me.
